# Setters & Getters "Mapping" Another Property Returning Undefined Using Angular's HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript, getter-setter, angular-httpclient

I'm experiencing some strange behavior regarding setters & getters that set/return another public property on the object in TypeScript when retrieved from Angular's (v5) `HttpClient`.

Here are the important constructs:

```
export interface NamedEntity {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    priority?: number;
}

export Rule implements NamedEntity {
      ruleId: number;
      ruleName: string;
      //..other properties

      get id(): number {
          return this.ruleId;
      }
      set id(id: number){
           this.ruleId = id;
      }
      get name(): string {
          return this.ruleName;
      }
      set name(name: string){
           this.ruleName = name;
      }
}

//Another class that implements NamedEntity in the same way
```

I'm retrieving `Rule` objects using the `HttpClient` as such:

```
 return http.get<Rule[]>("my url");
```

When subscribing to that `Observable<Rule>` I've found that all the properties that are not getters/setters display without an issue both in my debugger and within my angular templates.  However, the setter/getter based properties always display undefined in the debugger, and blank on my angular template.

My angular project was set up with Angular-CLI and my tsconfig.json has the target set to "es5".

This is most likely because the `HttpClient` casts the data into the shape that is the `Rule` interface that is generated by TypeScript.  How would I have the resulting objects from the `HttpClient` call be instances of the concrete `Rule` class rather it's implicit interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would need to see more code to be sure ... but I would guess that you are expecting your http request to return a Rule object. It does not. Instead it returns its data with properties as defined by the Rule object. Meaning it does not have any of the object's getters, setters, or methods.

If your object is general flat (no hierarchy) you could do something like this:

```
x = Object.assign(new Rule(), rule);
```

Where `rule` is the value back from the Http call.

This code creates a new Rule object (that then has the getters, setters, and methods) and copies the data into it.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case, and the HttpClient simply casts it to the generated interface Rule instead of the class.  How do I have it create an instance of the actual concrete class, instead of the generated interface?  (I'll update my question)